# ASP.NET MVC Pass Auth info to ViewModel from Controller Method Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am reworking one asp.net MVC Backoffice for full multi tenant support.

As I decided to use sharding for a perfect separation between tenants I need to access some Auth info (tenant Id) in every viewModel, only with that info I can create the right connection for the specified tenant.

For passing that info I have 3 rules:

- **I don't want to use session variables**
- **I don't want to use ViewBag**
- **I don't want to add a new Object to every VM for get auth info**

Most of all I want a "code less" solution, the perfect scenario would be getting access of auth info inside the VM for example passing it as a attribute in the controller call.

I already override Controller OnAuthorization so that it adds the tenantId to my base controller (which is the base of all my controllers) every time it is called, that way I can always catch tenantId inside every controller, now I just need a way to pass that TenantId in a attribute to every VM , something like the following pseudo-code

```
    [Authorize]
    [TenantId AS A PARAM]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        myViewModel vm = new myViewModel();
        vm.method();

        return this.View(vm);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Put this `TenantId` into `HttpContext.Curent.Items`

2) Write a static function that returns this `TenantId` from the context:

```
    private static int GetTenantId()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Items["TenantId"];
    }
```

3) Create a `BaseViewModel`

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public Func<int> GetTenantIdFunc{get;set;}
}
```

4) Using Dependency Injection container register your `GetTenantId` function and inject it through property injection to all your models

Comment: I ended up using DI despite it was not my first choice. I didn't use HttpContext because my previous implementation was strong enough to ensure that every time e invoke a method in the controllers i have direct access to Tenant Id

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a base view model and inheritance:

```
public abstract BaseViewModel()
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public void SetAuthInfo(BaseController controller)
    {  
        this.TenantId = controller.TenantId;
    }
}

public MyViewModel() : BaseViewModel
// no other changes needed to MyViewModel
...

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.SetAuthInfo(this);

    return View(model);
}
```

To get this via an attribute (rather than `model.SetAuthInfo`) add an action filter and override `OnResultExecuted` and add it there, something like (untested) :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class SetTenantActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var baseController = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;
        if (baseController == null) return;

        var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as BaseViewModel;
        if (model == null) return;

        model.TenantId = baseController.TenantId;
    }
}
```

then you could add this to your base controller (even less code than adding to every action)

Comment: I like your suggestion, just one problem , in that filter implementation model will always be null , because Controller.ViewData.Model is null

Comment: actually using OnResultExecuted is not appropriated because I want the filter to execute before the viewModel action and not after it

Comment: ok - I didn't manage to try it out so will take your word that it's null after passing the model to the view `return this.View(vm);`. It's not clear what you actually want.

Comment: I need to execute the filter after creating the viewModel but before executing the method.. I need to acess TenantId inside the viewModel method so that i can redirect my dbconnection to the correct shard

Comment: Then use the pre-edit version and simply call `model.SetAuthInfo(this);`